# Understanding Transition faults

Tags: testing, vlsi, dfm

I learned that the transition faults model checks whether data transition meets the clock or not

> Transition Faults : Assumes large delay defect concentrated at one
>   logical node, such that any signal transition passing through this
>   node will be delayed past the clock period.

Question is "This was already taken care of in timing convergence during the design cycle, is this same as post-silicon timing check? And can we reduce the frequency and make chip work in case of delay fault"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing two different ideas. Timing convergence during the design cycle will detect **design errors**, which can be corrected during the design process. A **transition fault** is a fault that occurs during manufacturing or operational use, such as a poor contact that has abnormally high resistance or a wire that is too narrow. You want to be able to detect these faults in your **acceptance test**, which the test you run on manufactured devices. The acceptance test procedure is usually much different from the functional test that you use in the design cycle, and there is an incentive to make the acceptance test as short as possible to save money during testing.

Comment: We won't model uncertainty of "such as a poor contact that has abnormally high resistance" in design cycle, because this is anamoly like stuck at fault?

Comment: Yes, a **fault** is an anomaly. However, you **can** model it during the design cycle, just as you can model a stuck at fault. Having said that, I don't have a practical example of a set of tools that will model transition faults or delay faults automatically.